# Getting contents of string, between two given sub-strings, using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, split

I'm trying to do some string operations in Python 3, and am struggling with a complicated issue which may be solvable in regex. I've tried to implement this myself but with no luck whatsoever.

I think I require a split() operation of some description, with a regular expression inside catching strings contains '===SOMETEXT==='.

The string type contains a series of headings, with paragraphs of content below. **I want to somehow be able to extract the content between headings.**

Example input:

> ===Camcorders===
> {{main|Camcorders}}
> A camcorder is an electronic device combining a video camera and a video recorder. Although
> marketing materials may use the colloquial term "camcorder", the name
> on the package and manual is often "video camera recorder". Most
> devices capable of recording video are camera phones and digital
> cameras primarily intended for still pictures; the term "camcorder" is
> used to describe a portable, self-contained device, with video capture
> and recording its primary function.
>
> ===Professional video camera===
> {{main|Professional video camera}}
> A professional video camera (often called a television camera even
> though the use has spread beyond [[television]]) is a high-end device
> for creating electronic moving images (as opposed to a [[movie
> camera]], that earlier recorded the images on [[filmstock|film]]).
> Originally developed for use in [[television studio]]s, they are now
> also used for [[music video]]s, [[direct-to-video]] movies, corporate
> and educational videos, marriage videos etc.
>
> These cameras earlier used [[Video camera tube|vacuum tubes]] and
> later electronic [[Image sensor|sensors]].
>
> ===Television video camera===
> .... etc

The text between the '===' strings may vary, but always follow the pattern '===HEADING-HERE==='.

Example output from query for 'Camcorders' section:

> A camcorder is an electronic device combining a video camera and a
> video recorder. Although marketing materials may use the colloquial
> term "camcorder", the name on the package and manual is often "video
> camera recorder". Most devices capable of recording video are camera
> phones and digital cameras primarily intended for still pictures; the
> term "camcorder" is used to describe a portable, self-contained
> device, with video capture and recording its primary function.

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex to catch everything in between `===`:

```
(?<=(===)).*(?=(====))
```

You can use this regular expression to return a list of matched words, then get the content between that matched word and the next heading by adding to the following regex:

```
(?<=(FOUNDHEADING===)).*(?=(===))
```

The python code for this will look something like this:

```
# IMPORT
import re

# FIND LIST OF HEADINGS
myre = re.compile(r"(?<=(===)).*(?=(====))")
list = myre.findall('Your text with ===HEADINGS=== here')

# POSSIBLY LOOP FOR EACH MATCHED HEADING

# GET CONTENT FOR FIRST HEADING
myre = re.compile(r"(?<=("+list[0]+"===)).*(?=(===))")
content = myre.findall('Your text with ===HEADINGS=== here')
```